# how can i isolate the number from str in the same data set

Tags: python, data-science

My list

```
a=['100Dollar','200Dollar','100Euro','300Euro','184pounds','150pounds','10rupee','30rupee']
```

My code

```
def data_table(data=a)

    for row in a:
        value=[]

      if 'Dollar' in row:
            print(row[0:])
            price, currency =row.split('D')
            currency=currency.replace('ollar','Dollar')
        value.append(int(price))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

re.match( '([0-9]+)(.*)','100Dollar').groups()
```

gives:

```
('100', 'Dollar')
```

You can extend this to your list:

```
[ re.match( '([0-9]+)(.*)',i).groups() for i in a ]
```

gives:

```
[('100', 'Dollar'),
 ('200', 'Dollar'),
 ('100', 'Euro'),
 ('300', 'Euro'),
 ('184', 'pounds'),
 ('150', 'pounds'),
 ('10', 'rupee'),
 ('30', 'rupee')]
```